# How to use RPi model 3B+ as Router with highest bandwidth? (VPN)

Tags: networking, wifi, ssh, access-point, openwrt

Basically, I'm trying to use my Pi as a VPN-Protected router and AP. I've tried RaspAp (hostapd with a web gui and some extra stuff) and hostapd by itself, but hostapd by itself wouldn't work with my VPN for some reason, and RaspAP was very slow (like 5mbps). I have two Pi's, both Pi 3B+'s, and I might try to hook them up in mesh later.

Right now I am using Ethernet in, and NOT the Pi's inbuilt wifi but instead a ThinkPenguin Wifi Adapter (I couldn't find a link to it, sorry). I just need some way to use my Pi as a router with my VPN. OpenWRT seemed to work ok, but I had two problems:
A. The LuCI Web GUI didn't seem to detect my WiFi adapter, even though it was built to run natively and works just fine on raspbian
B. I couldn't SSH into it without having it directly connected to my computer via ethernet, therefore I couldn't install any packages because it wasn't connected to internet.

If anyone has any suggestions or fixes for the issues above, anything would be very appreciated! thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "with highest bandwidth"? if you're using a pi3B+ as a router, the "highest" bandwidth possible is limited by the PI's ethernet - which is about 300Mbps - you'll be lucky to get near that with most VPN's - so RaspAP was 5Mbit, what did you achieve with OpenWRT?

Comment: The Pi would make a mediocre router - you can buy a better router for less than the price of a Pi.

Comment: @Milliways yes, but I already had this lying around and I want to put it to good use.

Comment: @JaromandaX I only get 150 mbps from my ISP, and it’s WiFi so I’m not expecting TOO much, all I need is enough to stream video on two devices simultaneously, so like 50 mbps or so. When I used HostAPD by itself, I had 30 mbps, so it is probably possible. As I said in the post, I didn’t get OpenWRT working with  my wifi adapter, so the connection was very slow.